# Mongoose: try to remove referenced objects using $pullAll

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In a nodejs app using Mongoose, I have a relation has many: App has many AppClients.

Models:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const appSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  appClients : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'AppClient' }]
})

appSchema.pre('remove', async function(next) {
  const app = this
  await AppClient.remove({_id: {$in: app.appClients }}).exec()
  next()
})

const App = mongoose.model('App', appSchema)

module.exports = App

const appClientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  field1: String,
  field2: String
})

const AppClient = mongoose.model('AppClient', appClientSchema)
```

What I wanted is to use $pullAll to remove the AppClients documents referenced in the App. I tried with:

```
appSchema.pre('remove', async function(next) {
  const app = this
  await App.update( { _id: app.id }, { $pullAll: { appClients: app.appClients } } ).exec()
  next()
})
```

but this not work. Does not throw any error but the 'app.appClients' are not removed> I was following the docs and can´t find out any problem/gap.